# How can I see Passwords in Console on Mac instead of ******?

Tags: macos, console, passwords

I want to update my Android App, but have a problem with my key password. After days I finally found it in the console log on my mac, but its hidden with ******.

2019-06-29 11:02:59,165 [ thread 36]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - [-Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=/Users/MyName/Desktop/KeyStore, -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=*********, -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=key0, -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=*********, -Pandroid.injected.apk.location=/Users/MyName/Desktop/MyApp/app, -Pandroid.injected.signing.v1-enabled=true, -Pandroid.injected.signing.v2-enabled=true]

Is there any way of getting to the real password? I also tried it in Android Studio with the 'executionHistory.bin' and had the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

You said you found that snippet in a log, which means to me that it's just a text file you're looking at. This means those *** you see are just text, so you won't be able to recover the password from them.

Many applications save passwords to your system keychain, have you tried looking there? The application you want to look at is Keychain Access which should be in `/Applications/Utilities`. When/if you find an entry that interests you, double-click it and click "Show Password".

Comment: Thanks, but it is not in keychain. :(